# How to track network packets of firebase analytics?

Tags: android, firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics, network-monitoring

I want to learn more about the mechanism of Firebase analytics.
I've tried monitoring using the network profiler in android studio. But, 
 network packets generated by firebase analytics could not be verified.
I could only see the message "Network Profiling Data Unavailable".
Is there any way to check using other tools?

Comment: Try using Firebase performance monitoring. https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/

Answer (score 0):

Charles Proxy is a very useful tool for checking network requests, responses and offers a lot more functionality too that makes it an essential part of my development workflow. There is a 30 day trial available here: https://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: For future readers: I've spent hours trying to sniff Firebase traffic using Charles. You'll be able to read most requests from your app but googleapis.com and other relevant Firebase APIs just don't connect.